# Unable to deserialise kafka topic in a stream using avro serialisation

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, quarkus, avro

I have a Quarkus project and a kafka producer which has

```
SpecificAvroSerializer<MyObject>
```

which writes successfully to topic and I can see the message ok

Then I attach a stream to this topic with

```
  SpecificAvroSerde<MyObject> myObject = new SpecificAvroSerde<>(schemaRegistry);
```

But during the message processing inside the stream I still get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record and org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @3c0a50da)
```

looks like there is a problem with QuarkusClassLoader when trying to cast the result to  SpecificAvroSerde

Comment: This is the Avro library saying you're trying to downcast, not Quarkus... There's a property in the deserializer that you have to explicitly set specific avro reader

Comment: @OneCricketeer which property?

Comment: I forget exactly but it's something like `value.deserializer.specific.avro.reader=true`, at least for Confluent deserializer https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer ... it worked ... can you write an answer so I can accept as correct sollution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that a GenericRecord cannot be downcast to a more specific type (SpecificRecord).

The default behavior of the Confluent Deserializer is to use GenericRecord, and you need to explicitly tell it to use SpecificRecord (or ReflectDatum) Avro types

```
value.deserializer.specific.avro.reader=true
```

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html